# Understanding a proof of a theorem from S.Roman's "Advanced Linear Algebra"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

There is a Theorem $1.5$ on page $43$ of the book "Advanced Linear Algebra" by Steven Roman.

> Theorem $1.5$. Let $F = \{ S_i | i \in I \}$ be a family of distinc subspaces of a vector space $V$. The following are equivalent:
>
> $1)$ **(Independence of the family)** $\forall i \in I \ \ S_i \cap \sum\nolimits_{j \neq i} S_j = \{0 \}$
>
> $2)$ **(Uniqueness of expression for zero)** The zero vector  cannot be written as a sum of nonzero vectors from distinct subspaces of $F$.
>
> $3)$ **(Uniqueness of expression)** Every nonzero $v \in V$ has a unique, except for order of terms, expression as a sum
>
> $v = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} s_i$
>
> of nonzero vectors from distinct subspaces of in $F$.

So, here goes the proof(from the book):

> $1) \Rightarrow 2)$
>
> Suppose that $2)$ fails, that is,
>
> $0 = s_{j_1} + ... + s_{j_n}$
>
> where nonzero $s_{j_i}$'s are from distinc subspaces $S_{j_i}$. Then $n > 1$ and so
>
> $-s_{j_1} = s_{j_2} + ... + s_{j_n}$
>
> which violates $1)$. Hence, $1) \Rightarrow 2)$
>
> $2) \Rightarrow 3)$
>
> If $2)$ holds and
>
> $v = s_1 + ... + s_n = t_1 + ... + t_m$
>
> where the terms are nonzero and $s_i$'s belong to distinct subspaces in $F$ and similarily for $t_i$'s, then
>
> $0 = s_1 + ... + s_n - t_1 - ... - t_m$
>
> By collection terms from the same subspaces, we may write
>
> $0 = (s_{i_1} - t_{i_1}) - ... - (s_{i_k} - t_{i_k}) + s_{i_{k+1}} + ... + s_{i_{n}} - t_{i_{k+1}} - ... - t_{i_m}$
>
> **Then $2)$ implies that $n = m = k$ and $\forall u = 1,2,...k \ \ s_{i_u} = t_{i_u}$. Hence, $2) \Rightarrow 3)$**.
>
> $3) \Rightarrow 1)$
>
> Finally, suppose that $3$ holds. If
>
> $0 \neq v \in S_i \cap \sum\nolimits_{j \neq i} S_j$
>
> **then $v = s_i \in S_i$ and $s_1 = s_{j_1} + ... + s_{j_n}$, where $s_{j_k} \in S_{j_k}$ are nonzero. But this violates $3)$**.

Now, I explain what I don't understand.
I don't understand the highlighted parts of the proof. That is,

$1.$

> **Then $2)$ implies that $n = m = k$ and $\forall u = 1,2,...k \ \ s_{i_u} = t_{i_u}$**.

Why does it imply that? I cannot see a logical step towards it.

and

$2.$

> **then $v = s_i \in S_i$ and $s_i = s_{j_1} + ... + s_{j_n}$, where $s_{j_k} \in S_{j_k}$ are nonzero. But this violates $3)$**

Why does it violate $3)$. I can't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question note that the pairing in

$$0 = (s_{i_1} - t_{i_1}) - ... - (s_{i_k} - t_{i_k}) + s_{i_{k+1}} + ... + s_{i_{n}} - t_{i_{k+1}} - ... - t_{i_m}$$

is such that it is a sum of elements in distinct subspaces. Hence all of these terms must be zero. Since the $s_i$,$t_i$ are non-zero, we see that there cannot be terms $s_{i_{k+1}},\dots,t_{i_m}$, hence $n=m=k$. Also since all terms must be zero, $s_{i_j}=t_{i_j}$ for all $1\leq j\leq k$.

For the second question, note that we have written $v$ as a sum of elements in distinct subspace in $2$ different ways:
$$v=s_i$$
$$v=s_{j_1} + ... + s_{j_n}$$
But three says exactly that we can only write $v$ in $1$ unique way a sum of elements in distinct subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

1. 0 cannot be expressed as a sum of non-zero vectors from distinct subspaces of $\mathbb{F}$. Since each term in that sum lies in a different space, then each term must be zero (else a contradiction). So if $n>k$, that would mean that there were terms that contributed to a sum that was zero. This would be a contradiction. Similarly, $m=k$.

Once  you realize that $n=m=k$, then each of the remaining terms in the sum must be zero, so $s_{i_u} = t_{i_u}$ for all $u$. Otherwise you would have a sum of things from different subspaces being zero, a contradiction.

2. You had a typo in your question, it should read $s_i = s_{j_1}+\dots+s_{j_n}$. So $s_i$ has two representations, one that we listed above, and another as $s_i = s_i$.